# How can I combine box plot and line graph in Python?

Tags: python, boxplot, linegraph

I'm trying to combine my boxplots and line graphs in the same place on Python. How can I merge/combine them?
Thanks in advance
Best

Comment: Did you allready try something?

Comment: I know that it is shown how to plot line and boxplot separately and there are answers for both them "separately". And, I know how to "plot" them "separately". So, I didn't think it's necessary to put the codes that are displayed already everywhere.  Otherwise, I'm aware what I'm supposed to do and don't need your passive aggressive behaviour. You can simply ignore my question and go away

Comment: Which library do you prefere?

Comment: It doesn't matter actually, yet I guess pandas would be much easier because I managed to plot the whiskers using pandas.